# CSS class not having an effect on a div

Tags: html, css

The following is an section of my CSS file plus some HTML. Can anyone tell me when I put class="containerHeader selected" (as is on Test Header A) the background color is not being set to Red?

```css
div#builderContainer
{
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 390px;
  height: 700px;
  border: solid 0px #CCCCCC;        
  background-repeat: no-repeat;    
}

div#builderContainer .container
{
  display: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; /* Corner radius */
  border: solid 1px #999999;

}

div#builderContainer .container div:hover 
{
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

div#builderContainer .containerHeader
{
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; 
  background: #93c3cd url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-small_50_93c3cd_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat; 

  border-bottom: solid 0px #999999;    

  margin: 0px;      
  margin-top: 25px;      
  padding: 10px;    

  /* display: none;  */

  border: solid 1px #999999;    
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background-color: #FFF;        
  cursor: pointer;    
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div#builderContainer .containerHeader:hover
{
  background: #ccd232 url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-small_75_ccd232_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat;
}

div#builderContainer .containerHeader:active
{
  background: #db4865 url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-small_40_db4865_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat; 
}

div#builderContainer .containerHeader .selected
{
  background-color: Red;        
}
```

```html
<div id="builderContainer">

  <div class="containerHeader selected" id="CHA">Test Header A</div>    
  <div class="container" id="CA"></div>

  <div class="containerHeader" id="CHB">Test Header B</div>      
  <div class="container" id="CB"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers (and to you Richard JP Le Guen).

I've tried all your answers but still no joy.

To clarify this is what I am trying to do...

On a div with class="containerHeader" I want to apply certain styles.  Then if I define the div with class="containerHeader selected" I want the div to now have all the  characteristic but the  now have the selected styles applied.  

Just writing this makes me ask the question, which style takes precedence if they both have say a border style defined????

Am I approaching this completely wrong?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use selector div#builderContainer .containerHeader.selected without the space.

Answer (score 3):

`div#builderContainer .containerHeader .selected` probably specifies the .selected as a child of containerHeader. Have you tried defining it as `#builderContainer .selected` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to comma separate your CSS rules.

I think you're expecting `div#builderContainer .containerHeader .selected` to apply to `div#builderContainer`, `.containerHeader`, and `.selected`, but what it's really applying to is a `.selected` *inside* a `.containerHeader` *inside* a `div#builderContainer`.  Instead, comma separated them:

```
div#builderContainer, .containerHeader, .selected {
     background-color: Red;
}
```

**Or**, if you meant for it to apply to only an element with both classes `containerHeader` and `selected`, inside the 'builderContainer', remove the space between those two.