# Why is my CSS class not being applied to the specified element?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on making some changes to this website: http://www.hairtothequeenbook.com/fr/ . Namely I'm trying to position the button that says "English" in the top right corner of the page.

Here is the button in the HTML:

```
<a href="http://hairtothequeenbook.com" class="language btn">English</a><br>
```

I've then created a CSS class that looks like this:

```
a .language .btn {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

(I only put the `!important` to see if there was something else overriding my styles.. needless to say.. wasn't helpful).

When I use Dev Tools and apply the styles, all works as it should, but when I actually modify the CSS file and upload it to the server - nothing changes.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I keep trying different tweaks to no avail...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS class not having an effect on a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556519/css-class-not-having-an-effect-on-a-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write it as

```
a.language.btn { ... }
```

(no spaces in between - it's all the *same* element, the `a` tag having those two classes)

Comment: Just to note for the OP spaces are a "descendant selector" so they are trying to select a `.btn` that is a descendant of a `.language` that is a descendant of an `a` tag.

Comment: Ahh but of course.. always the little things. This is great to know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`a .language .btn` with spaces means to target element with class `.btn` that is inside an element with class `.language` which is inside anchor.

to target the anchor with those classes use:
`a.language.btn`  without spaces